# PowerShell 2.0 get string's length

Tags: powershell

I have error in below, I need to match exactly between names and name's length.
I did not get any number.

```
 $CountName=$arrNames | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $searchName}  | measure-object -character | select -expandproperty characters;
```

Comment: Without knowing what $arrNames and $searchName are it is impossible to say what the issue is. Most likely $arrNames does not contain a record where the Name property equals $searchName. Strike that. Before Measure-Object add `Select -Expand Name|`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are passing objects, not strings, so it can't measure characters, because objects don't have them. You need to expand the Name property before you can measure how many characters it has.

```
$CountName=$arrNames | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $searchName}  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | measure-object -character | select -expandproperty characters
```